# Python Selenium - Finding & Clicking Element by aria-label or other custom fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

The following element is what I'm trying to click on via Selenium:

```
<com-calendar-date tabindex="-1" date="2021-09-28" presentation="compact" role="presentation" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="Tuesday, September 28, 2021 undefined" disabled="" style="pointer-events: none;">
```

This element is in a shadow DOM, so xpath is not an option.

This element is from a calendar, so every date begins with the tag: com-calendar-date.

My last attempt was as follows:

```
button = shadow_root4.find_element_by_css_selector("""com-calendar-date[date="2021-09-28"]""")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Is there a way to key off this custom field?

Comment: Can you please share your full code snippet which you are using to interact with the element and some more details if possible? So we can try at our end and find/share the solution for this. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes it works by not specifying the tag, try `button = shadow_root4.find_element_by_css_selector("[date='2021-09-28']")`